# Licensing SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition for development and test severs

Tags: sql-server-2012, testing, license

Is there an economic way to license SQL Server standard edition on a test server?

Given the following environment:

- live: SQL Server 2012 Standard Edition
- test: SQL Server 2012 Developer edition
- dev: SQL Server 2012 Developer edition

The problem with this scenario is that a developer could code using a feature that works in developer edition, but is not available when deployed to the live server.  The client would be the first to discover the problem!

Thoughts:

- Host test database on live server?

  - Doesn't give the live/test isolation I would like
  - Uses live server resource (buffers, CPU, etc.)
  - (Could disconnect test database when not in use to minimise this)
- Run a second database instance on the live server

  - Still poor live/test isolation
  - More processes using server RAM/CPU

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licencing which is an inherently transient topic. Please call Microsoft Sales.

Comment: In my defence, I tagged it with sql-server-2012 and it's been an issue for me since about sql2005.  I did call Microsoft but they just sent me to technet homepage.

Comment: I'd be open to suggestions as to where would be an appropriate place to post this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is certainly an economical way to do this - get an MSDN subscription. The licenses that you get allow you to use the software specifically in development and test environments. It looks like currently $1,199 would cover your needs for SQL Server (and assuming you can make use of some of the other software too), but you could always invest more to get additional software:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/subscriptions/buy/buy.aspx

Also, we've been asking for the ability to tell Developer Edition what our target edition is for ages. Please vote and comment on these items, explaining your use case and what you have to do to get around the problem:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/496380/enable-sql-developer-edition-to-target-specific-sql-version

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/664953/target-platforms-by-allowing-disabling-features-in-developer-edition

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/507277/allow-developer-edition-to-emulate-feature-set-of-different-editions

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/420180/implement-a-configuration-option-that-allows-a-sql-server-developer-edition-instance-to-behave-as-a-standard-edition-instance

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/331297/developer-edition-in-standard-workgroup-mode

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/125239/edition-compatability-level-in-developer-edition

The more comments, the better!

This feature should also make it into SSDT at some point. But they're only going to do it if there is enough customer noise about it. :-)

Comment: "MSDN subscriptions include all SQL Server editions for development and test" http://www.directionsonmicrosoft.com/licensing/30-licensing/4064-licensing-sql-server-for-development-and-test.html

Comment: +1, this is available more or less in SSAS (deployment target) and should be available in database engine too!

Answer (score 4):

Another thing that you could do that was even more economical is to use the developer edition and then run the following query against the database before deploying:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features
```

This will then tell you if you are using a feature that is not supported in all editions of SQL server, so if this returns no rows, you are ok to deploy to standard edition.

Link: [MSDN: sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280724.aspx)

Comment: +1 very useful.  I'd still be concerned that other parts of our system (.net) could dynamically generate an SQL statement that's not supported on standard edition.